# Why revision version and other attributes are not shown in repo-browser of Tortoise SVN for some branches

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

In Repository Browser of Tortoise SVN I see some branches as grayed out and no information like Revision or Author are shown for sub-folders and files. Other branches are fine.

I really wondering what does this mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just click on those grayed folders. They're only gray because the additional information for those hasn't been fetched.
The repo browser does not fetch the additional info if there are too many folders in one parent folder because it would take too long. So it only fetches the essential info, but shows those items in gray to indicate that you can force the fetch of the additional info.

Comment: Yep. This is the answer to my question. And if you press F5 (refresh) the whole grayed out tree will be updated. Thanks